# Android how to get results from another app

Tags: android

I have seen some apps that take me into a web page and after reach certain endpoint the browser closes itself automatically then I continue in the original app.

Another app that takes me to my SMS messaging app then autofill the textbox and when I click send, again the same thing happens the SMS app closes itself and then continue in the original app, how can I get the results of those intents.

In both cases, the app returns with data received I think it's from the backend

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Android deeplinks](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking)

Basically you create some deeplink for your app like `yourapp://awesomeintent` and the website calls this link. In your AndroidManifest.xml you register some activity for this deeplink with the help of intent-filters and then your app pops up as soon as any other app/website opens your deeplink.

Keep in mind: If the user has more than 1 app which can process the deeplink, Android will ask him which app he wants to choose to do so.